# Mediafire Privacy

Tags: ip, logging

In their [Data retention policy](https://www.mediafire.com/policies/data_retention.php) Mediafire states about the download records:

> These are short term logs of who accessed and downloaded content from whom’s account. We keep this for the minimum amount of time necessary to ensure resumable downloads etc.

I’m specifically talking about me accessing someone else’s account:

- What would most likely be in these short term logs that could identify a downloader or a viewer? An IP address? Or maybe your account, assuming that you were signed in?
- Would a website this big only retain information for this little of time because of liability? Or customer service?

Comment: Assumption is the mother of all epic fails. It probably will be the information you can find in any web server log. This means, a timestamp, a client IP address, user-agent and the content that is downloaded. In my opinion this would fit perfectly in the legal compliance part of the policy (stored for 10 years) but I am not a lawyer.

Comment: This is the kind of thing to ask them. We can only guess.

Comment: I was thinking what was stored for 10 years was the “account email, name, account holders ip address,etc.” that owns the content